# How can I get the recognition result to a file?

Tags: cloud, speech

I am not a programmer. But there was a need to recognize the audio file in the text. I recognized the audio file using the Gcloud console. But when I try to output the result to the console, an incomplete result is displayed and in an uncomfortable format:

**gcloud ml speech operations wait 4449209833501955641**

```
...
        "alternatives": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.91782826,
              "transcript": " you can fight... "
           }
         ]
         },
     {
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.8954131,
              "transcript": " all right I'll say it's a it's really good to hear and
     let's see if maybe a couple more questions and then I think we'll wrap it up he
     re do you trade options at all"
            }
          ]
         },
        {
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "confidence": 0.9671178,
              "transcript": " I do not not right now I mean I got enough where I just think ..."
            }
          ]
        },
...
```

Tell me a simple way to extract the result without re-recognition (the file is too large)!

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is data in JSON format. Without programming knowledge what I suggest is that you use a JSON to xx online service. For example, if you want to transform this JSON data into a .csv file which you can open in a Excel Spreadsheet, you can use [this service](http://convertcsv.com/json-to-csv.htm).

Comment: Thanks. But this is a solution for part of the problem. How do I extract the full result? In the console, I do not see full JSON.